# Indy TLS server with non-ASCII characters in private key password

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy, indy10

I have a private key file encrypted with a password that also contains non-US-ASCII characters (e.g. passwörd or s€cret).
I didn't find a way to use this key file from an indy based server, as Indy seems to use MBCS to convert the unicodestring password to an octet string.

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8018 (end of section 3) UTF-8 is a common encoding rule for password octet string.

According to my investigations Indy (I'm using the version that comes with Delphi 10.2 Tokyo) uses IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault inside PasswordCallback (IdSSLOpenSSL.pas) to convert the (Unicode)String to a PAnsiChar.

IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault() (in IdGlobal.pas) sets GIdOSDefaultEncoding to TIdMBCSEncoding and also returns it. GIdOSDefaultEncoding is not globally available and I also didn't find a method to set it.

Is there a possibility to either change the encoding PasswordCallback uses or already pass the password as byte array/PAnsiChar/RawByteSting to Indy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to change the charset that Indy uses for encoding Unicode passwords. You would have to alter Indy's source code and recompile it.  In a future version, I'll consider changing it to UTF-8, or make it user-configurable.

Note that `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault` is MBCS only on Windows. It is UTF-8 on other platforms.

Otherwise, you would have to call OpenSSL's `SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb()` function directly to replace the password callback with your own function, then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks! This should do it (although I didn't have time to test it yet.) Is there a better way to get the `PSSL_CTX` required for that call than writing a class helper for `TIdSSLContext` returning fContext?

Comment: @Chris no, there isn't